# Parsing a JSON array from a JSON object

Tags: beginner, json, kotlin

So its my first time using Kotlin, and for now I am converting old Java code to Kotlin. I took a simple function to parse a `JSONArray` from a `JSONobject` with a key. Here is the code:

```
fun getJSONArrayFromObject(jsonObject: JSONObject, key: String): JSONArray {
    var array = jsonObject.optJSONArray(key)

    if (array == null) {
        array = JSONArray()

        val tmp = jsonObject.optJSONObject(key)

        if (tmp != null)
            array.put(tmp)
    }

    return array
}
```

Is this idiomatic Kotlin, syntax-wise?

One more thing, since input parameters are final, am I supposed to convert them into a dummy object, like a copy object? I'm currently handling that as follows:

```
fun parse(data: MyData?, myObject: JSONObject) : MyData {
    var dataCopy = data

    if (dataCopy == null)
        dataCopy = MyData()

    if(myObject.optJSONObject("testing") != null) {
        val mySecondJson = myObject.optJSONObject("pc")

        if(mySecondJson.optJSONObject("testingSecond") != null) {
            val myJson = mySecondJson.optJSONObject("myJson")

            val myDataParser = MyDataParser()

            data?.myDataList = myDataParser.parse(myJson)
        } else {
            debug { "Missing" }
        }
    } else {
        debug { "Missing"}
    }

    return dataCopy
}
```

Comment: Which `JSONObject` / `JSONArray` classes are you using? From which library?

Comment: Normal Java classes